# detecting a change in the page including refresh

Tags: url, detection

so i am working in a .tpl file meaning i am open to js, html and php answers. what i want to do is whenever a person refreshes the page, experience a change in the url or exits the browser, my site would take an action based on this change of state. so basically, when they leave that specific page of mines in any way, i would call a function. the reason i want this is because i am saving this editable image on my site. but whenever they leave the page, i want the image the created to be autosaved.

Answer (score 0):

this task splits into client-side and server-side parts. At client side you should bind to interesting browser events, triggering some background http requests to some service URLs of your website, this is probably JS. At the server side, you should provide corresponding reaction to these requests, which is probably PHP.

As long as these service URLs are to be called intermittently by various visitors, be sure to keep an eye on what request came from which client's window. PHP sessions should help you.

I'd propose to work this separately, first to get saving machinery working -- just bind everything to explicit big buttons at the page (`page close`, `url change`, etc), then replace each button with the binding to exact JS event. Keep in mind differencies among browsers.

Comment: right i get that, but what functions can help me out here. i know for jquery there is this hashchange kinda thing, but is there something here that will tell me if the person refreshed or changed the page or exited browser?

Comment: read about javascript events that you could bind to: when page is closed, when url is changes. you may even detect the moment when mouse leaves the document area.

Comment: so i used the window.onbeforeload and it works on chrome, but when i go into firefox, it doesnt work anymore...any more advice please

Comment: the latter is separate, narrow JS-related question. try to google it or post it separately.